# Number of binary sequences with all nonnegative autocorrelation coefficients

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, inequality, binary, correlation

Consider sequences $x$ of length $n$ with binary values $x[i] = \pm 1$. Compute the linear autocorrelation coefficients $a[k] = \sum_{i=1}^{n-k} x[i] x[i+k]$. A  binary sequence with all nonnegative autocorrelation coefficients has $a[k] \ge 0$ for all $k = 0\cdots n-1$.

Give the number of such binary sequences amongst the  $2^n$ possible sequences, where these numbers are dependent on $n$.

With computer evaluations, here are the numbers for $n = 2 \cdots 20$:

2           2           2           6          10          12          14          24          52         74          98         170         326         506         712        1192        2230   3630        5588

It can be seen that the increase rate is not 2, i.e. the numbers do not double (as $2^n$ does) with each rising n. Indeed, the fraction of the $2^n$ possible sequences falls to 0.0508 at n=10 and to 0.0053 at n=20.

Can someone come up with ideas which describe (estimate / limit) this behavior with $n$? Does the fraction fall to 0 as $n \to \infty$? Will the increase rate converge towards some factor less than 2, or even towards 2 eventually?

Comment: Could you please clarify the question? It's not clear which set of sequences you are considering.

Comment: Dear Dan, I consider all sequences (amongst the $2^n$ many binary sequences of length $n$) in which all $n$  linear autocorrelation coefficients $a[k]$, as defined above, are  nonnegative. For example, for $n = 2,3,4$ these are only the sequences with all 1's and all -1's. For $n=5$, 4 additional sequences show up, namely  $ 1     1     1    -1     1$ and $1    -1     1     1     1$, and their negated counterparts , hence we have 6 such sequences. For larger $n$, the numbers are given.

Comment: The following looks useful. http://people.math.sfu.ca/~idmercer/cpc_art_2.pdf

Comment: Thanks, Dan, for finding the source. I read the paper which is concerned, however, with the absolute value of the correlations, whereas I address nonnegative correlations.